# <Not solved yet> How can I run a program on a tty?

Tags: linux, initramfs

I need tty interactive on onboot of linuxkit.

Now, `setsid -w agetty -a root -L 38400 ttyS0 vt100` is working.
But I want to run a specific program. Is there a way?

---

Thanks to "Mahdy Mirzade" for reply,

```
$ setsid sh -c 'exec ls <> /dev/tty2 >&0 2>&1'
```

This works pretty well, but It can't control the tty.

```
$ setsid sh -c 'exec sh -c "echo hello > /dev/tty" <> /dev/tty10>&0 2>&1'

(error message) cannot create /dev/tty: Inappropriate ioctl for device
```

Therefore, it is impossible to operate a program that receives user input through tty. Is there any way to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try passing `sh -c` to your command:

```sh
$ setsid sh -c 'exec ls <> /dev/tty2 >&0 2>&1'
```

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work. "Usage: agetty [options] <baud_rate>,... <line> [<termtype>]"

Comment: @user212942  edited my post, worked and output on tty2, but not sure why you're using `agetty`, but `agetty` is also a program, your command is already running `agetty`, to run other porgram you'll need to run sh to execute it or running a program with std output after `setsid`.

Comment: Actually I didn't quite understand setsid and agetty. This method works fine! thank you :)

Comment: This works pretty well, but It can't control the tty.

setsid sh -c 'exec sh -c "echo hello > /dev/tty" <> /dev/tty10>&0 2>&1'
cannot create /dev/tty: Inappropriate ioctl for device

Therefore, it is impossible to operate a program that receives user input through tty. Is there any way to solve this?

Comment: @user212942 I believe you need to pass your input to your program using `stdin` or standard input, like when `stdout` is usable when you store it like `VAR=$(ls)`, you may also insert your queries to your specified program, before running in the first place using `--stdin`, but there is also an article that might help you more about user input: https://ryanstutorials.net/bash-scripting-tutorial/bash-input.php

Comment: Unfortunately, it is difficult because the program was not made by me.

Comment: @user212942 Maybe repost your new issue with new title? because it's marked green and people might not see it that often? - My answer is that I don't know how it's done but there is always who knows this, we need to show it to him.

Comment: Okay Thank you :)